# Unable to click on web element using HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

1. Go to : http://list.qoo10.sg/item/REAL-JAPAN-VERSION-WORTH-120-24K/412131433
2. Scroll down till you reach Customer review table
3. Down the table there is paging tab looks like this

> < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 >

what i need to click on    `>`
which means to the next page of the table

and the code i used

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://list.qoo10.sg/item/REAL-JAPAN-VERSION-WORTH-120-24K/412131433");        
WebElement findElement1 = 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td#opinion_point_1.rating"));          
String htmlTableText = findElement1.getText();
System.out.println(htmlTableText);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
//next click    
WebElement click_button = 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#paging.pagingInfo div.center a.next"));      
boolean click2=click_button.getAttribute("href").contains("javascript:opinionList(2)");  
click_button.click();
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10); 
WebElement findElement2 = 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td#opinion_point_1.rating"));          
String htmlTableText2 = findElement2.getText();
System.out.println(htmlTableText2);         
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

I print the element before the click & after but it doesn't change. This means that the click is not performed. Any suggestions?

I've tried the following fixes but I got the same results

```
click_button.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

and

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(click_button).click().perform();
```

and

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
click_button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.cssSelector("div#paging.pagingInfo div.center a.next")));
click_button.click();
```

Comment: Is it htmlunit error only?

Comment: code has run without errors but the click have no response

Comment: Is it htmlunit result only? Did U tried with other Drivers?

Comment: i tried FireFoxDriver() & i get this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;

Comment: It might not be the best method to suggest, but did you try clicking the button using javascript?

Something like this

`WebElement element = driver.findElement (By.xpath ("Your xpath or CSS"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript ("arguments[0].click();" , element);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to click on the 'next page', using the following xpath, this xpath points exactly to the `>` icon:

```
//Wait for the next button
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
click_button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Xpath("//div[@id='paging']//a[@class='next']/span[text()='next']")));

//Click next button
click_button.click();
```

Then, after click try to wait for the `[2]` (ie second) page icon is highlighted. This site sets class 'current' for the selected page:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Xpath("//div[@id='paging']//a[@class='current'][text()='2']")));
```